# Best way to visualize time series where data only exists in seasonally

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, time-series

The question is pretty simple but I'm unclear if the solution is.  I have basketball player stats that I want to visualize over time and sometimes I want to visualize it across multiple seasons (years).  They don't play year-round so there are generally about 6 months where there is simply no data.

If I don't care necessarily that the dates on the x-axis are scaled accurately, is there a good way to visualize these multiple seasons without a) having massive gaps in the graph and b) interpolating a physically long line filler?

Comment: convert the dates into string and plot?

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for response.  Can you help me understand how that would help?

Comment: @SamDillard This would help because if the dates are strings, then they would be interpreted as a categorical variable. While the dates 2020-01-01 and 2020-06-01 clearly have dates that fall in between them, the strings '2020-01-01' and '2020-06-01' don't have any inherent meaning except the order in which they are seen by the plotting library

Comment: @DerekO Oh, very good!  Not only is this going to help but it will be a good tool for future!